# Calling another executable and capturing output

Tags: powershell, dacpac, sqlpackage

Using a PowerShell script I'm trying to execute `SqlPackage.exe` to update a database. The problem is that it spawns a new CMD window and I can't capture the output effectively.

Here is my script:

```
&$SqlPackage "/Action:Script", "/SourceFile:$($Environment.PackageFile)", "/Profile:$($Environment.PublishProfile)", "/OutputPath:$($Environment.ScriptFile)";
```

where `SqlPackage = "SQLPackage\SqlPackage.exe";`.

Strangely when I execute the script on a Windows 2008 R2 web server the output is inline with the PowerShell output, which is ideally what I want. On my Windows 7 machine it spawns a new CMD window.

How can I route the output to the PowerShell window all the time, or at least pipe to another file?

*Edit*

Full solution with waiting for process to finish:

```
$p = Start-Process $SqlPackage -ArgumentList @("/Action:Script", "/SourceFile:$($Environment.PackageFile)", "/Profile:$($Environment.PublishProfile)", "/OutputPath:$($Environment.ScriptFile)") -NoNewWindow -Wait -Passthru
$p.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If the question doesn't make sense I can update it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the result you are looking for if you use `Start-Process` with the `-NoNewWindow` parameter:

```
Start-Process $SqlPackage -ArgumentList @("/Action:Script", "/SourceFile:$($Environment.PackageFile)", "/Profile:$($Environment.PublishProfile)", "/OutputPath:$($Environment.ScriptFile)") -NoNewWindow
```

If you need to direct the output to a file you can also use the `-RedirectStandardOutput` / `-RedirectStandardError` parameters of `Start-Process`

Comment: Perfect! I need to wait for the process to finish before executing the next statement, I presume that is possible too? I've tried -Wait but it doesn't seem to work.